# Is there a way to have jqPlot CategoryAxisRenderer put the graph lines & tickMarks on the category & not in between?

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, jqplot

[image: Category Axis Renderer Example]

This plugin puts the categories **between** the graph lines & tick marks.

I would like the graph line, tick & label to be aligned on the y-axis.

[Category Axis Renderer Plugin Reference](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-categoryAxisRenderer-js.html)